vb.net: split json (container??) string
How can i DeSerialize a Json String looking like this:
[[5389809,"*Bella*@",0,"",0,"","y",1],[9888723,"bizarre",0,"",0,"","y",1],[9889781,"violate",0,"",0,"","y",1],[1510819,"xeno",1,"",0,"","y",1]]

i tried using an Object Class like:
Public Class MyFriendsList
    Public Property Array() As List(Of CategoryContainer)
End Class

Public Class CategoryContainer
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property user As String
End Class

but that does not work.
Error is:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: "Cannot deserialize the
current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'xMessenger.MyFriendsList'
because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to
deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a
JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to
an array or a type that implements a collection

Thanks for any Ideas!

The data doesn't really represent a structured class, it's just an array of arrays of both integers and strings.  Unless there's a way to change the structure of the source data, it's something like List(Of List(Of Object)) where Object is boxing either a String or an Integer.

The input is NOT VALID JSON. Correct JSON would look something more like this: [{"id":5389809,"user":"*Bella*@","otherfield":0,"fourthfield":"","fifthfield":0 ... },{"id":9888723,"user":"bizarre","otherfield":0,"fourthfield":"","fifthfield":0 ... }, ... ]

any chance of getting an example maybe on howto put the source into a list(of object))?

If your array entries [5389809,"*Bella*@",0,"",0,"","y",1] have some fixed schema for each index (corresponding to the properties of CategoryContainer), then this may be a duplicate of How to deserialize an array of values with a fixed schema to a strongly typed data class? and/or Deserializing JSON in Visual Basic .NET.
